# Maximise the probability of a linear combination of random variables

Tags: estimation, random-variable, extreme-value

I have a data set representing a random vector $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots, X_p)'$.
Define $Z=\alpha' X $, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\alpha'\mathbf{1}_p =1$.

I would like to find the $\alpha$ which maximises the likelihood of $Z$  falling in a given interval $(a,b)$, that is:
$$
\max_\alpha\; \mathbb{P}\left[\alpha' \mathbf{X} \in (a,b)\right]
$$

The task is relatively simple if the $X_i$ variables are assumed normal i.i.d.. 
Can you tell me some methods, and related R packages, for a more general case?

### Edit

To make the problem solvable, perhaps numerically, I assume $\mathbf{X}$ follows a  skewed-$t$ distribution.

Comment: This may be stated too generally to permit any effective answers: based on what you have given, your objective function could be literally any function of $\alpha$ that takes on values between $0$ and $1$.  Perhaps you could make it more specific by providing more information about the multivariate distribution of $X$?

Comment: @whuber: I am now assuming a skewed-$t$ distribution.

Comment: Could you make your edit more precise? IID skewed-$t$? ???